# Pig filter matches not working with pig and EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-pig, emr

I would like to filter all the strings that contains internal, but the data is not filtered. In my pig scripts I have:

```
preload = load '$INPUT' as (textline:chararray);
filterdata = FILTER preload BY SIZE(textline) > 100;
filterInternal = FILTER filterdata by NOT(textline MATCHES '.*internal.*');
```

Using Pig 0.12.0 on AWS

Answer (score 0):

Load with textloader as your input dataset is not tab separated.

I tried below example and it worked

a = load 'matches' USING  TextLoader AS(line:chararray);

b = filter a by not (line matches '.*imran.*');

dump b;